# How to get nested list items values only in Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I've a list and I can print that list. But, I've another list inside the list. Can I only get the specific item inside the nested list?

**For Example:**

```
import json

x = {
  "name": "John",
  "age": 30,
  "married": True,
  "divorced": False,
  "children": ("Ann","Billy"),
  "pets": None,
  "cars": [
    {"model": "BMW 230", "mpg": 27.5},
    {"model": "Ford Edge", "mpg": 24.1}
  ]
}

# convert into JSON:
y = json.dumps(x)

# the result is a JSON string:
print(y)
```

Here, if I just want only car model to print, how can I print?

Like, model = BMW230

Can you please help? Thank you.

Comment: That's a nested dictionary, not a list.

Comment: `print(x['cars'])` ?

Comment: You don't have a *list*, you have a *dictionary*

Comment: why are you converting it to a string, `json.dumps` converts it to string

Comment: Thank you all for your answer. I'm new to Python and learning. So you might see some wrong sentence used like lists and dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data structure `x` is a dictionary. If you want to just print the car models from the dictionary `x`, you can use a *list comprehension*:

```
print([car['model'] for car in x["cars"]])
# ['BMW 230', 'Ford Edge']
```

Or you can print each model with a normal `for` loop:

```
for car in x['cars']:
    print(car['model'])

# BMW 230
# Ford Edge
```

As shown above, to access dictionary *values* you need to specify the key, like `x['cars']`, where `'cars'` is a *key* in the dictionary. You can have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more helpful information on how to use dictionaries.

Comment: @user3217606 No worries, glad I could help :)